# Angular Material - Element overlay on images (in md-card)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to reproduce the following using angular material (that is to say, add dynamic text over an image) :
[text over image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3xNC.jpg)

I would like to use md-cards because there are convenient.

My problem is that I cannot manage to make the text overlay on the image; the text is always before or after the image.

Is playing with the position in CSS the only solution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You do not want any CSS at all? Few lines of CSS can achieve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a wrapper. Something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="md-card-wrapper" ng-app="myapp">
  <md-card>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OiqxTL1.jpg">
  </md-card>
  <span>Text over image</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.md-card-wrapper {
  position: relative;
    width: 40%;
  span {
      position: absolute;
      top: 20%;
      right: 20%;
      color: white;
      font-size: 34px;
    }
}
```

Or you can play with my example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xEpvOv

Comment: I think he's trying to avoid CSS.

Comment: Indeed I was trying to avoid css and use as much as possible Angular Material native options/functionalities.

For instance, the wrapper option works (thanks by the way) but when I change the size of the browser window the text and position do not scale whereas Angular Material is (more or less) dealing natively with these issues.

Comment: There is no built in Angular Material solution for text overlays, and yet they are in the Material specification. Which means doing it yourself following the spec is totally fine.